# Erro ao usar câmera do android dentro de aplicação

Tags: java, android

Estou implementando um app onde preciso usar a câmera para tirar uma foto e salva-la na galeria, no entanto estou obtendo um erro quando tento executar um comando para fazer esse procedimento.

```
public class CaptureImage extends AppCompatActivity{

    private static final int CAMERA_IMAGE = 2;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private Uri uri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_capture_image);

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivImgSelected);
    }

    public void useCamera(View view) {

        Intent it = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        uri  = Uri.fromFile(Util.createImage()); // Util.createImage() => Cria um arquivo com o endereço padrão da galeria
        it.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri); // erro acontece aqui
        startActivityForResult(it, CAMERA_IMAGE);
    }
}
```

Após alguns testes conclui que o erro acontece quando tento executar o comando `it.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri)` dentro do método `useCamera(View view)`. Removi essa linha de código e o app abre a câmera normalmente. O problema é que eu preciso desse comando para que minha aplicação salve o arquivo devidamente, sem ele a aplicação não salva a imagem.
Alguém pode me ajudar com este problema?

O erro apresentado é:

> android.os.FileUriExposedException:
>   file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/1715784088086.jpg

A versão do SDK que estou utilizando para rodar o app é a API 26

Comment: Mas qual é o erro?

Comment: Poderia, por favor, editar a pergunta com o erro que está mostrando, e também informar qual o targetSdkVersion do app. Pode ser algum problema de permissão de acesso.

Comment: Opa, desculpem a demora. Acabei de editar a pergunta detalhando o erro e a versão do SDK utilizada.